# trying to match two occurrence of couples in a query result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to catch one concept of mysql, as example I'll take a db for 2on2 basket games. The tables are:

```
matches(**matchid**,teamAId,nationalityAOd,teamBId,nationalityBId)
teams(**teamId**,playerAname,playerBname)  
nationalities(**natId**,natName)
```

teams and nationalities tables were created for limiting the redundancy of the same occurrences (USA USA USA....)
Is there a way to get a result of a query to be the full data of the games, like

1 jim jake USA tony joe ITA

2 carlos gabriel SPA dan chris ENG

......

grouped by matchId? The concept is simple, but all the queries I tried weren't good because if i say

```
WHERE teamAId=teamId AND teamBId=teamId
```

I obviously get nothing,because that looks for games in which teams were playing versus themselves, but if i say

```
WHERE teamAId=teamId OR teamBId=teamId
```

I get two records per match, each one with the data for just one team, and it's not what I'm looking for.Sorry for the dumbness of this, I thank in advance whoever is gonna give my a hint! Cheers

Comment: If you have 2 records for every game, that means that you can skip one part of the condition. Use __WHERE teamAId=teamId__ only.

Comment: hi! that would return only one team involved like 1 jim jake USA and no data for the other team! with the OR condition I get "1 jim jake USA" then "1 tony joe ITA" on two rows, but I would want them on the same record...

Answer (score 0):

You could use **INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.PlayerAName, t1.PlayerBName, n1.natName,
       t2.PlayerAName, t2.PlayerBName, n2.natName
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.teamID = m.teamAID
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t2.teamID = m.teamBID
INNER JOIN nationalities n1 ON n1.natID = m.nationalityAID
INNER JOIN nationalities n2 ON n2.natID = m.nationalityBID
WHERE m.matchID = <match id here>
```

This should allow you to put data from multiple rows in the same row, and filtered by match id since they are in common. Just put the match id in the where clause.

Comment: All right!I have some hard times in the different types of join, I'm gonna review them. Thanks a bunch!